# Bounding box across multiple pages with Prawn PDF

Tags: ruby, pdf, prawn

I'm trying to create a document with Prawn Ruby PDF generator, but I'm facing the following problem:

The image below shows what structure I'm trying to do.

[image]

And this is the example code that tries to mimics my real scenario with the way that I'm trying to achieve this. The `2.times` and `(50.times.map { |i| i.to_s }.join("\n"))` mimics dynamic data.

```
require 'prawn'

class MyPdf
  def self.to_pdf(*args)
    new(*args).to_pdf
  end

  def to_pdf
    pdf.move_down 200

    2.times do
      pdf.bounding_box(
        [0, pdf.cursor],
        width: pdf.bounds.width
      ) do
        pdf.text (50.times.map { |i| i.to_s }.join("\n"))
        pdf.stroke_bounds
      end
    end

    pdf
  end

  def pdf
    @pdf ||= Prawn::Document.new(page_size: 'A4')
  end
end
```

But I'm having a lot of trouble with the dynamic bounding box placing.

[image]

Do you people know a way to achieve this with or without bounding boxes?

Answer (score 1):

You may be looking for [`span`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sandal/prawn/Prawn%2FDocument%3Aspan):

```
def to_pdf
  pdf.move_down 200

  2.times do
    pdf.span(pdf.bounds.width) do
      pdf.text (50.times.map { |i| i.to_s }.join("\n"))
      pdf.stroke_bounds
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I failed to do that with boundig boxes. May be this is not the best solution, but you can do this with tables :

```
data = []
500.times do |i|
    data.push [i.to_s]
end

table(data, width: bounds.width) do |t|
  t.cells.border_width = 0 # We don't want to see a table
  t.before_rendering_page do |page|
    page.row(0).border_top_width = 1
    page.row(-1).border_bottom_width = 1
    page.column(0).border_left_width = 1
    page.column(-1).border_right_width = 1
  end
end
```

source : http://prawnpdf.org/prawn-table-manual.pdf (page 17)

Check your margins to have the continuation on the top of the next page